# why dont 2 inline-block divs with combined width equalling that of the parent fit side by side?

Tags: css, width

I can't figure this out.

I can get it to work by floating it, but I would like to understand why this is happening.

[pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EwKboo)

code:

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: purple;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.item.left {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: green;
}

.item.right {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item left"></div>
  <div class="item right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant why *dont't* they fit side by side, that's because inline elements are sensitive to white space in your code. Remove the space between the divs and they line up on the same line side-by-side:

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: purple;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.item.left {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: green;
}

.item.right {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item left"></div><div class="item right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ah, thanks! you answered so fast I can't even mark this as the answer yet!

Is there anyway to accomplish the same thing without having really long lines in my code?

Comment: You can also place comments between the lines like `<div class="item left"></div><!--            ---><div class="item right"></div>` or float them.

Comment: thanks! i actually ended up recalling that fix from a while back. How is this normally dealt with at the professional level? Is the white space comments considered a 'hack'? Is it better to use floats? It seems like perhaps I shouldn't be doing it this way if I have to do some weird commenting stuff, no?